# Stop Qgis layer from refreshing every time I pan

Tags: qgis

I've got a layer in a QGIS project which source is a PostGIS view. It's a quite complex view and needs like 20 seconds to load (it makes several spatial analysis).

My problem is that the QGIS project becomes unmanageable because every time I pan it loads the layer again and gets stuck another 20 seconds..

Is there any option to disable for this QGIS project, or even better, for this layer to stop requerying data every time I pan the map?

Answer (score 7):

You can stop QGIS from loading the data by deselecting `Render` at the bottom of the window, see screen shot (taken from QGIS 2.16).

This not only keeps it from rendering the data on the user interface, but also from loading new data from your data source.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It can be the closest workaround to what I want, but it is not exactly what I want....because the layer gets totally frozen and if you zoom the pixels get bigger and bigger...I would need something that lets rendering active but I gues it does not exist..

Comment: True, it's not ideal. The only other thing I can think of is to file a [feature request](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#steps) and ask the nice people of QGIS to solve it.